# Accessing Facebook basic information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How can I access the basic information of a user without using authentication mechanism (**no access token**). Either graph api or by using FQL, doesn't matter.

**Flow of the program:**

- the client logs into the system
- enters a facebook id in a text field
- hits submit
- system returns the basic information, no authentication is being done

Comment: you could try hacking into facbook....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not do that.  Basic information about a user needs authentication.

The only action you can do without authentication is retrieving public information - however this is limited to the privacy settings for each user - ie. it depends on what information the user has made public.